# What is the number of (binary) 4 x 4 matrices over GF(2) (the field with 2 elements) that do not have an eigenvalue of 0 or 1

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, finite-fields

My code below returns 4032.  The [OEIS sequence A002820](https://oeis.org/A002820) says there are 5824 such matrices.  Is there something wrong with my code.  I am assuming that the eigenvalues of a matrix are precisely the roots of the characteristic polynomial.  If the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is irreducible over the underlying field then the matrix has no eigenvalues.   Right?

```
Count[Map[
  IrreduciblePolynomialQ[CharacteristicPolynomial[#, x], 
    Modulus -> 2] &, Tuples[Tuples[{0, 1}, 4], 4]], True]
```

Comment: The characteristic polynomial could have irreducible quadratic factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
noLinearFax[mat_] := 
 Module[{x}, 
  With[{fax = 
     FactorList[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x], Modulus -> 2]},
   (Length[fax] == 2 && fax[[2, 2]] != 4) || (Length[fax] == 3 && 
      Rest[fax][[All, 2]] === {1, 1} && 
      Map[Exponent[#, x] &, Rest[fax][[All, 1]]] == {2, 2})]]

AbsoluteTiming[
 Count[Map[noLinearFax, Tuples[Tuples[{0, 1}, 4], 4]], True]]

(* Out[506]= {12.913031, 5824} *)
```